# iOS decode umlaut &$

Tags: ios, nsstring, decode, diacritics

I have an example of what I need decoded:

> @"f&#252r"

How can I get this decoded to an NSString so it looks like

> fūr

I tried a number of things including

```
[@"f&#252r" stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] > f&#252r  
[@"f&#252r" gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML] > f&#252r
```

but no luck.

Thanks!

UPDATE based on vikingosegundo's solution

```
    NSLog(@"möchte decoded to :     > %@", [@"möchte" stringByEncodingHTMLEntities] );
    NSLog(@"m&ouml;chte decoded to: > %@", [@"m&ouml;chte" stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] );

    NSLog(@"für decoded to :     > %@", [@"für" stringByEncodingHTMLEntities] );
    NSLog(@"f&uuml;r decoded to: > %@", [@"f&uuml;r" stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] );

    NSLog(@"m&#246chte decoded:%@", [@"m&#246chte" stringByDecodingHTMLEntitiesComma] );
    NSLog(@"f&#252r decoded:%@", [@"f&#252r" stringByDecodingHTMLEntitiesComma] );

möchte decoded to :     > m&ouml;chte
m&ouml;chte decoded to: > möchte
für decoded to :     > f&uuml;r
f&uuml;r decoded to: > für
m&#246chte decoded:möchte
f&#252r decoded:für
```

Note : 
stringByEncodingHTMLEntities is from https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/tree/master/Classes
stringByDecodingHTMLEntitiesComma is from vikingosegundo's category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
[@"f&#252;r" stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
```

or

```
[@"f&#252;r" gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
```

(note the `;`)

[This category](http://pastebin.com/uVb3SKHK) also works with out the missing `;`.

Comment: awesome! Thanks. Will update my original answer with what I've done using your solution.